# Calculate subtotal and grandtotal of separate gridview in repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview inside a repeater. In gridview, there is a column TXN_AMT which contains a link button. When i click on the link button the subtotal and grandtotal or select a page index then the calculation is not displaying the correct value.

**Global variables**

Dim dSubtTtlTxnAmt, grandTotal As Double

**Repeater and gridview codes**

```
Public Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then Exit Sub

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim GV As GridView = e.Item.FindControl("GV")
        Dim ObjDS As ObjectDataSource = e.Item.FindControl("ObjDS")

        ObjDS.SelectParameters.Clear()
        ObjDS.SelectParameters.Add("dteDateStart", DbType.Date, Param.dteDateStart.ToString())
        ObjDS.SelectParameters.Add("dteDateEnd", DbType.Date, Param.dteDateEnd.ToString())

    GV.PageSize = 10

        ' Reset to 0, to prevent amount use by next record in repeater
        dSubtTtlTxnAmt = 0

        GV.DataSourceID = "ObjDS"
        GV.DataKeyNames = New String() {"ID"}
        GV.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GenerateFooter(ByVal oGV As RenderGridViewDataRow, ByVal sender As Object)


    Dim SubTotalRow As New List(Of RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField)
    SubTotalRow.Add(New RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField(dSubtTtlTxnAmt, RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField.DataType.Decimal, 2))
oGV.CreateTotalRow(SubTotalRow, sender, "Sub Total ", 3

    Dim GrandTotalRow As New List(Of RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField)
    GrandTotalRow.Add(New RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField(ViewState("grandTotal"), RenderGridViewDataRow.TotalRowField.DataType.Decimal, 2))
oGV.CreateTotalRow(GrandTotalRow, sender, "Grand Total ", 3

End Sub


 Public Sub ObjDS_Selected(sender As Object, e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

    ' ## Assign value to variables
    grandTotal = e.OutputParameters.Item("GRAND_TOTAL")

    ' ## Set Grandtotal to viewstate
    ViewState.Add("grandTotal", grandTotal)

End Sub


 Public Sub GV_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim oGv As New RenderGridViewDataRow

    If e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.Footer Then
        ' Generate footer
        GenerateFooter(oGv, sender)
    End If

    ' Render gridview data row
    oGv.RenderGridViewDataRow(e, sender)
End Sub

Public Sub GV_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)


    If e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        ' Calculate subtotal
        dSubtTtlTxnAmt += CDec(e.Row.DataItem("TXN_AMT"))

    End If

End Sub
```